# Request to run a task in a rest API

Tags: rest, api

I want to build a RESTFUL API.

I have a resource with task plans.

The client should request the server to run task such as benchmarking on one of the task plan metrics.

which request should be used. POST or GET?

and what should be the uri?

```
/api/plans/<id>/run or /api/plans/run/<id> ?
```

Comment: In general use `POST`, as `GET` is an idempotent and safe operation. As the semantics of a `POST` request is completly up to you, you can use it to issue a process trigger to the server. If the processing may take some time make sure to return a `202 Accepted` resonse code including a `Location` HTTP response header pointing to a resource the client can leran more on the current state of the process. A true RESTful service (and client) does not care much about the form of the URI though best practices recommend to avoid verbs as resource names as they convey RPC like semantics

Answer (score 1):

I will go for a POST and since is an action on a specific plan, the url should be `plans/id?action=run`.

run is not a sub collection of a plan so query param must be used in this case

Comment: Is using POST on an action for a resource is in accordance to RESTful standards?

Answer (score 0):

GET requests are used for reading/getting data. POST requests are for creating data.

If the user just needs to see the results of a benchmark run, I would use a GET request that returns the results of the benchmark method for the plan.

For retrieving a single record, the URL convention is `/things/:id`, so I would recommend `api/plans/:id/run`. I also recommend renaming `run` to something more descriptive, like `benchmark` or `metrics`.